# Range Based For Loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, heap-memory

My question is: When I use a range based for loop like in this example, is it releasing the memory on the heap in each 'Object' stored in 'vec'?  I had a thought that this was just copying a pointer, and then trying to release the copied pointer.

I believe 'auto *& obj : vec' is declaring 'obj' a reference to a pointer, and then assigning the address of each object stored in 'vec' to it, which its memory will be released, and set to nullptr. Is this right?

```
std::vector <Object*> vec;
vec.push_back(new Object{});
vec.push_back(new Object{});
//....

//clean up
for(auto *& obj : vec)
    delete obj, obj = nullptr;
```

Comment: That's not how you clean up a vector. It has it's own mechanism. Do you really need a vector of pointers? Use RAII

Comment: If you use objects instead of pointers, they will automatically be cleaned up once the vector goes out of scope, or you call the vector's emptying function

Comment: Your code looks good to me. From a stylistic point of view, I would rather use `{ delete obj; obj = nullptr; }`.

Comment: If you have range-based for, you have std::unique_ptr and should consider using it.

Comment: you need pointers iff you want to store multiple types from a type hierarchy.

Answer (score 3):

> When I use a range based for loop like in this example, is it releasing the memory on the heap in each 'Object' stored in 'vec'?

Yes.

> I had a thought that this was just copying a pointer, and then trying to release the copied pointer.

It does not copy the pointer. However, deleting a copy of the pointer does the same thing as deleting the pointer, so that would make no difference to whether the pointed object is destroyed. It does make difference to whether the original pointer is set to null in the assignment after the delete.

> I believe 'auto *& obj : vec' is declaring 'obj' a reference to a pointer, and then assigning the address of each object stored in 'vec' to it, which its memory will be released, and set to nullptr. Is this right?

This is mostly right. Although, if we are pedantic, that code assigns each object stored in `vec` to the reference. That is because the objects stored in `vec` are addresses of the `Object` instances.

Your need to clarify what the code does implies that it is not very good. In this case, you may benefit from not using `auto`:

```
for(Object*& obj : vec) {
    delete obj;
    obj = nullptr;
}
```

Also, consider whether it makes sense to store a vector of null pointers. I suggest that you don't set the pointers to null, but simply remove the pointers entirely:

```
for(Object* obj : vec)
    delete obj;
vec.clear();
```

Much clearer, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](Object* pt){delete pt; pt = nullptr;});
```

This should work.

Comment: The `pt = nullptr;` part doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: its not automatically set to a nullptr (not part of C++ standard as far as I can tell) and its never a good idea to have a vector of non-null pointers pointing to memory which has already been cleared and free to be reused by other bits of code.

Comment: All true but you are setting a function local variable to `nullptr`, `vec` still contains the `delete`d pointers.

Comment: Good point :), I missed that. So a reference to a pointer then?

Comment: Aside from not answering the question and containing an error (as pointed out by R Sahu). Be honest: Do you really think this is better than the OP's solution?